# Best way to use non blocking hid_read through between 2 threads

Tags: multithreading

I've used a bit the `hidapi lib`, both on OS X and on Linux (Raspbian).

Now I'm coming in need to attach to the Raspy two hid card readers.

Since the `hid_open` works as a protected channel for each hid eventually discovered by the `hid_open`, my "natural" idea would be to have 2 threads in which the two devices are managed, i.e. the main thread will create one thread for each device found. Within each thread, then I will do `hid_open` and non-blocking `hid_reads` from the devices. This should theoretically work, since the `hidapi` is meant to be thread safe.

I don't need to write to the devices, just to read from them, so I should not add any `udev` rule for that, since reading should always permitted.

Now my point is: which is the best method to implement this, in order to avoid CPU running waiting within each thread?

I would set non blocking mode for reads, of course. Then I would do a while (1) loop like this:

```
while(1)
{
    if ( hid_read() > 0 )
    // Manage result
    // ..
}
```

one for each thread. Is this correct, or I should do a nano sleep(something) after each read? I saw different ways, but I doubt about them all. Someone put a sleep ( better nano sleep ) before looping back, someone else is actually doing a thread yield instead.

May you eventually help me in doing the best way, please?

Answer (score 2):

Probably I realized by myself using the non-blocking solution + the while(1) is probably the worst approach to avoid CPU huge loading.
I've looked carefully within hidapi sources ( with libusb backend ) and I found the non blocking version is actually exiting immediately, which is what for it's meant to be, of course.
This would result the CPU always hanging at the while(1) statement, and from my experience this would load a lot the CPU.
Probably, the best solution to have the CPU waiting on that thread is to use the simple hid_read in its blocking version. Looking to its implementation, the libusb actually uses interrupts to wait for incoming packets, meaning the CPU should stop until an interrupt has been received, without wasting its time around the while(1) as in the non-blocking version.

So the code in my original post is working, just avoiding to set the hidapi to have non-blocking reads. this should also mean no timeout has to be used at all: just a bare, simple hid_read in a loop for each thread.

If anyone has experienced something like that, please eventully gently confirm my guesses.

thanks